# How to align this button to the right of the screen?

Tags: sencha-touch

I've tried adding style: float: right to the button but it isn't working.

```
myapp.cards.home.add({
         xtype: 'button',
         id: 'previmagebutton',
         // text: 'p',
         iconCls: 'arrow_left',
         iconMask: true,
         style: 'float: right'

     });


  myapp.cards.home = new Ext.Panel({
        scroll: 'vertical',
        id: "home-card",
        layout:{
            type:"vbox",
                            align:"center"

        },
        items: [header]
    }); 

  myapp.mainPanel = new Ext.Panel({
        fullscreen: true,
        layout: "card",
        cardAnimation: 'slide',
        items: [myapp.cards.home]
    });
```

I have to use the add method if that is what's causing the problem. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your `myapp.cards.home` object you have the layout set up to `align:"center"`.

Comment: Hi llya, that doesn't help unfortunately. After further experimentation it seems that one cannot float buttons in sencha touch or extjs, even if you create a simple example like a fullscreen panel with minimal configuration and just a button in it. Absolute positioning is the only way, unless the button is in a toolbar in which case you can use the spacer. If you find a way to use floats please do let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've succeeded in creating a floating button by using

```
    floating:true
```

config on the button. It is a private member, so I'm still looking for an official way.

Answer (score 0):

This should work ::

```
layout : {
    type : 'vbox',
    align : 'left'
}
```

or you can add a `spacer` if its in the toolbar, or if you `stretch` the element, then add another `hbox` element on its side with a `flex` that occupies as much space that you don't need